# 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types Numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, bitwise-and

I am trying to calculate F1_Score using numpy array using the code below

```
ypred = np.squeeze(imgs_mask_predict[jj,:,:,:])
ytrue = np.squeeze(imgs_test_mask[jj,:,:,:])

def f1_score_single(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = y_true.flatten('F')
    y_pred = y_pred.flatten('F')
    cross_size = len(y_true & y_pred)
    if cross_size == 0: return 0.
    p = 1. * cross_size / len(y_pred)
    r = 1. * cross_size / len(y_true)
    return (2. * (p * r) / (p + r))
```

I get an error

"ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' "  at this line of code

```
    cross_size = len(y_true & y_pred)
```

I tried to search for this error but did not get the reason and solution for this. How should I resolve this?

Comment: What are `y_true.dtype` and `y_pred.dtype`?

Comment: y_true type      <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
y_pred type     <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
y_true shape    (256, 160)
y_pred shape    (256, 160)

Comment: That looks like `type(y_true)` and `y_true.shape`.  Now show us `y_true.dtype` and `y_pred.dtype`.  The `dtype` attribute tells you the data type of the data in the numpy array.

Comment: dtype is float32

Comment: Ah.  Why are you trying to use the `&` operator (which for numpy arrays is bitwise-and) with floating point values?  That operator only makes sense (for some definition of "sense") with integer values.

Comment: I want to find the similarity between the image pixel in 2 images and not sure how to calculate the length of similar pixel values in both the arrays( y_true and y_pred).   I have used the same function for integer values in the past but as you said this can not work float32 values. Do you have any idea/hint to solve this problem which I can try?

Comment: If you want to filter by a max or min difference, evaluate if `y_true - y_pred > threshold`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `isclose` for floating point numbers.

```
cross_size = np.isclose(y_true, y_pred).sum()
```

You can also set a threshold for similarity by `atol` and `rtol` keyword arguments, [you can see the documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose).

Answer (score 0):

you can try intersect1d instead of &, for example, the use of np.intersect1d will do the same as you intend to do with &

```
import numpy as np
y_true=np.array([1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0])
y_score=np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,4.0])
x=np.intersect1d(y_true, y_score)
print(x)
```

the result will be [1. 2. 4.]

you can test the program here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/